# PHP Headers and client library minor version mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to connect with a mysql databse and I receive this Warning:

> **Warning**: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50173 Library:50312 in **/home/u709086394/public_html/config.php** on line **10**
>  voto_duplicado

my web is configured as PHP 5.2

this is my file

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
$db_username = 'u709086394_admin';
$db_password = 'password';
$db_name = 'u709086394_db01';
$db_host = 'mysql.hostinger.com.ar';

$db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name) or die('could not connect to database');
?>
```

I understand is related with the use of mysqli instead of mysql.

How I should  establish the connection on this case

Comment: Maybe look into shifting to pdo?

Comment: There seem to be something wrong with the configuration of your system or PHP-installation. Btw, you have posted login details in your question